# ¿Cómo puedo fusionar varias imágenes a través de un bucle utilizando la información de una dataframe (pandas) en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucle-for, imagen, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'],
                       'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 
                       'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
                       'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 
                       'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 
                       'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Para obtener cada posible permutación sin repetición en un orden específico (es decir, productos cartesianos) utilizo el siguiente código:

```
import itertools as it

AllKeysNames = ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas']
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```

Luego, para guardar cada iteración en una `df` de tal forma que arroje una salida como esta:

```
   |            Permutations            |                                    FilePermutations                                      |
  0|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None                         |
  1|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png                    |
  2|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png                   |
  3|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png                  |
  4|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png                    |
  5|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+None                 |
  6|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Arena.png            |
  7|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Marron.png           |
  8|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Purpura.png          |
  9|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Verde.png            |
  .
  .
  .
358|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Verticales.png+Zapote.png+Pinzota_pinzita.png+Purpura.png  |
359|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Verticales.png+Zapote.png+Pinzota_pinzita.png+Verde.png    |
```

Utilizo el siguiente código:

```
new = ['+'.join(x) for x in 
                            it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames))]
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Permutations':"+".join(AllKeysNames), 'FilePermutations':new})
```

Ahora, suponga que el programa anterior está ubicado en la misma ruta (es decir, `r"./"`) en la que *coincidencialmente* también se encuentran las siguientes carpetas:

[image: Folders]

Estas carpetas solo contienen imágenes de archivos, que *también coincidencialmente* tienen el mismo nombre de aquellos valores en `the_dictionary_list`.

**Como la variable `df` ha almacenado el orden correcto en el que estas imágenes deben fusionarse además de los nombres de archivo y carpeta, y también la cantidad total de permutaciones**

**¿Cómo podría este programa tomar esa información de** `df` **y usar las funciones de:**

`Image.open(r"./")`

`Image.alpha_composite()`

`resize((350, 350), resample=Image.NEAREST`

de `Python Imaging Library (PIL)`

¿Para producir las nuevas imágenes fusionadas en el orden en que las muestra el `df`?

- *Notas:*

> Los nombres de archivo de la imagen pueden ser iguales al índice respectivo de `df`.
>
> Como el elemento `None` no existe realmente en las carpetas, cuando sea necesario, el programa tendría que fusionar las imágenes anteriores con la siguiente (es decir, sin llamar a `Image.open (r "./")` ni a `Image.alpha_composite ()` cuando aparezca '`None`' y continúe haciéndolo con el siguiente elemento)
>
> Solo después de haber combinado las imágenes de archivo de una fila, llamaría `resize ((350, 350), resample = Image.NEAREST` para luego guardar la salida final usando `.save(r"./Test/str (Index(i))+".png")` y luego repita el proceso hasta que haya alcanzado el índice final de `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los DataFrames de pandas poseen un método llamado `iterrorws()` que nos devuelve un generador y podemos iterar en el y esto nos devuelve la fila en si en forma de tupla que contiene dos objetos, el primero es el índice de la fila y el segundo es una serie de pandas que contiene los valores de las columnas siguientes.

Yo no recomendaría unir con un `+` los nombres, simplemente los puedes dejar en formato de lista esto ya que posteriormente los vamos a necesitar como listas nuevamente y puedes ahorrarte esa conversión a lista evitando usar `"+".join(x)`.

```py
for i, per in df.iterrows(): #desempaquetamos el resultado en 2, i y per
    images = per["FilePermutations"].split("+")
    files = per["Permutations"].split("+")
```

con esto estamos obteniendo el valor la columna respectiva y volvemos a convertirla a lista con ayuda del método `split`. Una vez teniendo esto ya podemos pasar a crear la imagen nueva que es el resultado de unir todas las imágenes especificadas en la lista `images`. Para esto primero debemos saber el directorio de cada imagen y *"casualmente"* el primer elemento de la lista `files` es el directorio donde se encuentra la imagen del primer elemento de la lista `images` y así sucesivamente para cada una de las imágenes, por ello se me ocurrió usar la función `zip()` que empareja cada uno de esos elementos (en caso alguna lista tenga menos elementos solo emparejará hasta según la menor lista y no incluirá a los demás, en caso exista ese escenario puedes usar la función `zip_longest` del módulo `itertools`). Con eso ya tendríamos el `path` de la imagen, solo nos quedaría abrirla, combinarla y al final de todo redimensionarla y guardarla.

```py
for i, per in df.iterrows():
    images = per["FilePermutations"].split("+")
    files = per["Permutations"].split("+")
    result_image = None #aquí se almacenará la imagen resultante 

    for direc, img in zip(files, images): #iteramos
        if img=="None": continue #si es None omitimos

        path = f"{direc}/{img}" #definimos la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen
        
        #en la primera iteración no habrá imagen inicial por lo que no podrá combinarse con otra
        # por lo que asignamos la imagen
        if result_image == None: 
            result_image = Image.open(f"./{path}")
        else: #combinamos la imagen
            img2 = Image.open(f"./{path}")
            result_image = Image.alpha_composite(result_image, img2)
    # redimensionamos y guardamos
    result_image = result_image.resize((350, 350), resample=Image.NEAREST)
    result_image.save(f"./Test/image_{i}.png")
```

Esto combinará todas las imágenes especificadas en cada fila y las guardará en la ruta especificada. Como habrás visto no hay mucha magia en esto, solo un par de ciclos `for`, el primero para iterar en las filas y el segundo para crear el `path` y obtener las imágenes. En cada iteración del segundo `for` se sobrescribe el resultado de `result_image` para que siempre contenga el resultado de la combinación de la imagen actual y la anterior, de esta forma todas las imágenes se mezclan, obviamente se omiten las que no existen marcadas como `"None"`.

Comment: Eres el papu de los papus, +10 y a favoritos @Christian

Comment: He estado muy inactivo últimamente, pero me alegra poder volver a ayudar :D